# Get error code number from postgres in Go

Tags: postgresql, go, error-handling

I'm simply unable to retrieve the error code number when I get an error in postgres.

In the test of my program I know I'll get the following error 
" pq: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "associations_pkey"".

Looking in the postgres docs this is most likely an pq error code of 23505.

I need to get that number in my Go program so that I can check on different types of errors and respond to the end user in a helpful way.

However, I can't seem to get hold of the error code in Go, only the error message. My code is as follows:

```
stmt, _ := DB.Prepare("INSERT INTO table (column_1) VALUES ($1)")

_, err = stmt.Exec("12324354")

if err != nil {
    log.Println("Failed to stmt .Exec while trying to insert new association")
    log.Println(err.Error())
    fmt.Println(err.Code())

} else {
    Render.JSON(w, 200, "New row was created succesfully")
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to type assert the error to the type `*pq.Error`:

```
pqErr := err.(*pq.Error)
log.Println(pqErr.Code)
```

Comment: Thanks. However, If I insert that into my code I get the following compile error: /server.go:137: undefined: pq

Comment: You must've used the empty import. Instead of `import _ "github.com/lib/pq"`, write `import "github.com/lib/pq"` to actually import the package.

Answer (score 13):

This is [written in the documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#hdr-Errors). As you see you can extract it in this way:

```
if err, ok := err.(*pq.Error); ok {
    fmt.Println(err.Code)
}
```

Do not forget to remove the underscore from your import `_ "github.com/lib/pq"`. As you see `err` has a [lot of information about the error](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#Error) (not only `Code` but many others).

Notice that you can't compare it directly to some code (it is of `ErrorCode type`).

So you have to convert it to string and compare against a string.

https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#Error